# Dnu restore is required for any work with reference in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dnx

I have created a new ASP.NET 5 project in latest Visual Studio. When I try to add a reference to either my project, nuget or even edit project.json file I always get an error that says I have to run "dnu restore" manually because of some issues with project.lock.json file that wasn't automatically updated. Dnu restore does indeed help, but it's clearly a bug in Visual Studio. Any way to fix it?

Comment: Which version of DNX do u use in your project ? is it the default version ?

Comment: it is not a bug. you are using a beta version and it is been updated so something does not work as before

Comment: I have uninstalled all betas and use only rc1, I have created a project on rc1 from the start

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to check...

First of all, keep your project.lock.json file out of source control. `dnu restore` will regenerate it often.

Secondly, double-check your user environment variables. Make sure the following is in your Path:

```
C:\Users\<YourUserName>\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-final\bin
```

I have VS2015 Update1 RTM installed, and do not experience this, so I doubt it is a bug. If none of the above helps though, it may be an installation misconfiguration of your VS. Perhaps try it on another machine (or VM) if you can.

Comment: My runtime is called dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1, can that be an issue? Not sure why yours is called -final and mine is -udpate1. Also, why is that a problem if it's in the source control? proj file is as well, but Visual Studio does not have problems with it, nor does dnu restore called from command line have the problem...

Comment: I have just read that update1 is the newer version, perhaps you'll get the problem if you update as well :)

Comment: Aha. Run `dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-final -p`. Hopefully that should clear things up.

Comment: Why do I need to install (I don't have it in dnvm list) and use the rc1-final since update1 seems to bet the latest? Do you think that there is a problem with this latest update?

Comment: In solution explorer, right click the project and select "Properties". In the Application tab, there is a "Solution DNX SDK verion" dropdown. Does it say rc1-final or rc1-update1? I suspect it is the former, not the latter. Same question goes for your global.json file.

Comment: It is actually update1 in the project properties (and I don't have final at all) and in global.json as well, but all of the dependencies are -final. I don't know why...

Comment: There is nothing bad about rc1-final. I suggest you change the xproj and the global.json to use that since it matches your project.json dependencies. If you want to, you can replace the `rc1-final` parts of your project.json to `*` to see if that helps, like `"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-*"`